# Function Millis() Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, millis

I would like to make a countdown with arduino.
To do this I'm using the millis () function, but I have a problem, I can not reset this.
Reading on the internet I read that it is not possible to do this.
So how can I find an alternative for this?
In practice, when I pressed the button I started the countdown, while if I put it back, I went into the pause mode.

---

```
void inizio(){
  Serial.println("INIZIO");

  currentMillis1_general = millis();
  total_1 = currentMillis1_general - currentMillis_general;
  Serial.println(total_1);

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    step_funzione = 1;
    delay(200);
  }
}

void countdown(){
  Serial.println("COUNTDOWN");

  display.setBrightness(7);

  currentMillis_general = millis();
  total_general = currentMillis_general - total_1;

  if(total_general - previousMillis_general >= interval_general){
    previousMillis_general += interval_general; 
    //previousMillis_general = currentMillis_general;
    m = new_tempo/60;
    s = new_tempo%60;
    new_tempo--;
  }

  display.showNumberDec(m, true,2,0);
  display.showNumberDec(s, true,2,2);

  Serial.println(total_general);

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(buttonState == HIGH){
    step_funzione = 0;
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Comment: think about this ....How do you know when it is time to replace the oil in your car's engine? .... you cannot reset the odometer to zero

Answer (score 1):

A way to accomplish "Reset" is to set your starting value equal to millis() again. To do the equivalent of "Pause", you need a pause counter. When you begin a pause, save millis() to `pauseTime`. When you resume running again, add `millis() - pauseTime` to your pauseCounter. Then your interval should not expire until `millis() - pauseCounter > Interval)`.